# Is it possible to add a "go back" type function to the jQuery joyride plugin?

Tags: jquery, zurb-joyride

The question pretty much says it all... the homepage is [here](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) but I don't see anything related to going back, nor how I could add it myself.

Answer (score 1):

This Pull Request may be relevant for you : https://github.com/zurb/joyride/pull/7

You need to set: `'prevButton': true`   in your options

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - however its a very old pull request I think and no longer is fits the latest version :-(

Comment: Actually just found [this](https://github.com/nickschuch/joyride/commit/66fe50e03997c3f18e4d2d0ba0242ed44602cfa6#diff-22683db24395b9576c1a8bd132c1ad91R115) which is up to date

Answer (score 0):

It seems this [commit](https://github.com/nickschuch/joyride/commit/66fe50e03997c3f18e4d2d0ba0242ed44602cfa6#diff-22683db24395b9576c1a8bd132c1ad91R115) includes the right functionality although it doesnt come as standard in the plugin so you have to add in the bits from the commit but it does work fine!